# Fire same Model Event twice

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm dealing with the following code:

```php
// BaseModel
abstract class BaseModel extends Eloquent {
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::saving(function($model)
        {
            echo 'Fired BaseModel';
        });
    }
}

// Project (extends BaseModel)
class Project extends BaseModel {
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::saving(function($model)
        {
            echo 'Fired Project';
        });
    }
}
```

When saving new/existing data to the Project Model, this only gives me `Fired BaseModel`. It doesn't fire the Saving Event on the Project Model at all. Is there a way to overcome this limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fire the child event first before calling the parent event should solve it

```
// Project (extends BaseModel)
class Project extends BaseModel {
    public static function boot()
    {   
        static::saving(function($model)
        {
            echo 'Fired Project';
        });

        parent::boot();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I need the code in the BaseModel, to be handled first.

Comment: What are you actually doing in the BaseModel? Are you literally trying to echo something, or actual do something?

Comment: Try putting a Log() in the base model and the child model - it should work. Dont echo - it might be killing the event process...

Comment: Actually doing something. Things like Model authorisation, validation, custom events firing, transaction logging, etc.

Comment: In your parent event, are you "returning"? If you "return", it will stop the booting process then and there. You need to let it run through the whole process. I had this same issue with validating in my base model - I couldnt work out why my child event never fired - it is because I "returned" the validation as true!

Comment: Even though it was returning TRUE, the process indeed ended. Thanks for your help! PS: Log::info() didn't help.

Comment: @RonaldHulshof did you manage to keep validation in the basemodel?

Comment: Yes validation works perfectly on the BaseModel now. I now only return FALSE when I want the script to abort. Just never return anything else otherwise, to make the script continue as expected.